# Uniquifying a list (C#)

Tags: c#, linq, list, distinct

I'm trying to remove duplicates from a list using a custom equality comparer, but I can't seem to get it right.

Simplified example:

```
class A
{
    public A(string Test) { this.Test = Test; }
    public string Test;
    public string ToString() { return Test; }
}

class AsComparer: EqualityComparer<A>
{
    public override bool Equals(A x, A y)
    {
        return (x.Test == y.Test);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode(A obj)
    {
        return obj.Test.GetHashCode();
    }
}

static private void Test()
{
    var As = new List<A> { new A("Test1"), new A("Test3"), new A("Test1"), new A("Test2") };
    As.Distinct(new AsComparer());
    As.Sort((e1, e2) => { return (e1.Test.CompareTo(e2.Test)); });
}
```

This returns the collection "Test1", "Test1", "Test2", "Test3". I want there to be only one "Test1", but can't seem to figure out how to do this right.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Distinct` returns an `IEnumerable<T>`, it does not operate on the source list itself. You'll have to do:

```
As = As.Distinct(new AsComparer()).ToList()
```

You can also include your sorting here:

```
As = As
    .Distinct(new AsComparer())
    .OrderBy(x => x.Test)
    .ToList()
```

Answer (score 5):

`Distinct()` returns a brand new `IEnumerable`, so:

```
var result = 
  As.
    Distinct(new AsComparer()).
    OrderBy(e => e.Test).
    ToList();
```

Comment: Pretty sure that `Sort` is a method of `List<T>` and thus cannot be called on an `IEnumerable<T>`. Also `Sort` returns void: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6(v=vs.110).aspx - The Linq equivalent would be `OrderBy`: `As.Distinct(new AsComparer()).OrderBy(x => x.Test).ToList()`

Comment: @HenrikIlgen What was I thinking? Thanks, fixed!

Answer (score 1):

I think it be better to go with IEquatable on your class

```
class A : IEquatable<A>
{
    public A(string Test) { this.Test = Test; }
    public string Test;
    public bool Equals(A other)
    {
        return Equals(Test, other.Test);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != GetType()) return false;
        return Equals((A)obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            unchecked
            {
                return Test.GetHashCode();
            }
        }
    }

    public string ToString() { return Test; }
}
```

Then you can just do

```
var result = As.Distinct().OrderBy(x => x.Test).ToList();
```

Comment: That strongly depends on whether two `A`s are *always* considered equal when their `Test` property is the same (in which case you're absolutely right) or if two `A`s with equal `Test` are only considered equal in some cases (in which case it seems better to just use the appropriate `EqualityComparer`).

Comment: @HenrikIlgen You are correct. I posted code according to the sample class provided in the question.